# Can't configure network in kali

Tags: network-interface

I can't configure the network in Kali Linux manually every time I assign an IP with

Ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.100
Netmask 255.255.255.0
Default gateway 192.168.1.1

It gets configured and when I reboot my laptop it revert to previous stage automatically.

There is no IP address next to `inet` when I type `ifconfig`.

Comment: On a modern system you should _always_ prefer the `ip` tool to `ifconfig` (`ifconfig` roughly translates to `ip address`, or short `ip a` then). Just to give one example, if you assign multiple IPv4 addresses to one interface without the (old) method of aliasing (`eno1` as "primary" and then `eno1:0` ... `eno1:2`), `ifconfig` won't show you anything but the "primary" IP. However, `ip` will correctly show all assigned IP addresses.

Comment: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ifconfig` command is only used to modify network settings temporarily. You can't permanently change network settings with this command.
you will find your answer here:
[network configuration in kali linux](https://kali.training/topic/configuring-the-network/)

Comment: Hey Thanks for helping though but can you please help me in a more detailed way...I want to configure my eth0

Comment: @user237963 one question per Q&A please. Simply ask another question. Btw: the likely reason why your question got downvoted is because Kali isn't for beginners or the faint of heart. So if you need to ask about how to configure a network interface, you may want to stick to a simpler to use distro than Kali. Oh and welcome to SuperUser!

Comment: @ganeshreddychimmula are you certain Kali is using Netplan for this and not `/etc/network/interfaces` or so? Perhaps I'm not up-to-date ... and also to you: Welcome to SuperUser.

Comment: oh! my mistake ,i think its only available in  ubuntu 18.4 after versions. i just checked my kali vm,it  has network configuration files in /etc/network directory ,i will edit my answer and thanks for acknowledging me